# Calculating Manhattan Distance within a 2d array

Tags: java, distance, a-star

I am writing a program to solve an nxn 8 puzzle problem. I'm having difficulty with my Manhattan calculation function being off by two from the puzzle I'm testing my program with. This will eventually be expanded to use the A* pathfinding algorithm, but I'm not there yet.

Here is my function(which is based on the initial state of the board and not taking into account the amount of moves taken so far):

```
// sum of Manhattan distances between blocks and goal
public int Manhattan()  // i don't think this is right yet - check with vince/thomas
{
    int distance = 0;

    // generate goal board
    int[][] goal = GoalBoard(N);

    // iterate through the blocks and check to see how far they are from where they should be in the goal array
    for(int row=0; row<N; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<N; column++){
            if(blocks[row][column] == 0)
                continue;
            else
                distance += Math.abs(blocks[row][column]) + Math.abs(goal[row][column]);
        }
    }

    distance = (int) Math.sqrt(distance);

    return distance; // temp
}
```

This is the example I'm working off of:

```
 8  1  3        1  2  3     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 4     2        4  5  6     ----------------------    ----------------------
 7  6  5        7  8        1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1    1  2  0  0  2  2  0  3

 initial          goal         Hamming = 5 + 0          Manhattan = 10 + 0
```

My Hamming calculation is correct and returns 5, but my Manhattan returns 8 instead of 10. What am I doing wrong?

This is the output of my program:

```
Size: 3
Initial Puzzle: 
 8  1   3   
 4  0   2   
 7  6   5   

Is goal board: false

Goal Array: 
 1  2   3   
 4  5   6   
 7  8   0   
Hamming: 5
Manhatten distance: 8
Inversions: 12
Solvable: true
```

Comment: Who or what are vince and thomas?

Comment: Haha, those are the people I'm working on the assignment with.

Comment: Then why are their names in your code? Please clean up your comments

Comment: I guess I forgot to delete them before I posted this. Just curious, why is it such a big deal what I have in my comment? It's my own personal note to check with my classmates about whether or not I did it correctly.

Comment: On another note I have figured out the problem so I have edited the post as such.

Comment: Good questions are clean and tidy, brief as possible and to the point. Sloppy comments, or irrelevant comments, are not of use to future visitors. On the "other note", don't post answers in the question; post your answer as an actual answer: please remove your "solution" for the question and post an answer if you feel it's better than the answer currently posted (which I think is superior BTW)

Comment: Fair enough - just thought I would ask as I was curious what your reasoning behind the comment was. Clearly you are much more experienced than I when it comes to StackOverflow, so I will take your suggestions and apply them to future questions I have on the website. If I might make a suggestion, I would phrase those concerns in a less abrasive way; as it can sometimes come across harsher than you may have intended it. Thank you for the criticism, and I hope that you have a good rest of your day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error lies in the update of the distance.

In writing `distance += Math.abs(blocks[row][column]) + Math.abs(goal[row][column]);` you add all contents of the cells of initial and goal. Only one excluded in initial and goal is the cell with same coordinates as `0` in initial.

In your example this gives 2 times sum from 0 to 8 minus 5. `2 * 36 -8 = 64`. Then you take the square which is 8.

Manhattan - as described by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) is calculated by distance in rows plus distance in columns.

Your algorithm must lock like (beware, pseudocode ahead!)

```
for (cell : cells) {
    goalCell = findGoalcell(cell.row, cell.col);
    distance += abs(cell.row - goalCell.row);
    distance += abs(cell.col - goalCell.col);
}
```

And don't take the square root.